# xml to csv transformation value incrementation

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

i would like to transform an xml file to csv ( the structure above) and count the number of low nodes, i try to use

```
 <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
```

and number but i get always 1231212 what i would like to get is 1234567

```
<root>
    <row>
        <low id="1d" name="bio">FNO</low>
        <low id="1d" name="bbn">NBN</low>
         <low id="1d" name="afs">CAA</low>
    </row>
    <row>
        <low id="1a" name="adn">VHH</low>
        <low id="1d" name="bio">ADN</low>
    </row>
<row>
        <low id="1r" name="rio">BOA</low>
        <low id="1f" name="flo">KGG</low>
    </row>
</root>
```

someone can help please? thank you

the desired output :

```
 row  low  id name
  row1 low1  1d bio
  row1 low2  1c bbn
  row1 low3  1d afs
  row2 low4  1a adn
....
```

used xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row/low"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="low">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),',',.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post your XSLT and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number)

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <row>
        <low>FNO</low>
        <low>NBN</low>
        <low>CAA</low>
    </row>
    <row>
        <low>VHH</low>
        <low>ADN</low>
    </row>
    <row>
        <low>BOA</low>
        <low>KGG</low>
    </row>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="low">
    <xsl:number level="any"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
1,FNO
2,NBN
3,CAA
4,VHH
5,ADN
6,BOA
7,KGG
```

Alternatively, if you change the node set being processed, `position()` will work. In the example below, the only nodes being processed are `low` so `position()` works (produces the same output as above)....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row/low"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="low">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),',',.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would come in handy if you had to do something like sort the `low`'s before outputting the position. (You would just add `<xsl:sort/>` to the `xsl:apply-templates`.)

---

**EDIT**

Here's another example using your updated input and desired output. This output is a little different than your desired output because it is comma separated. Replace the commas with whatever separator you want.

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <row>
        <low id="1d" name="bio">FNO</low>
        <low id="1d" name="bbn">NBN</low>
        <low id="1d" name="afs">CAA</low>
    </row>
    <row>
        <low id="1a" name="adn">VHH</low>
        <low id="1d" name="bio">ADN</low>
    </row>
    <row>
        <low id="1r" name="rio">BOA</low>
        <low id="1f" name="flo">KGG</low>
    </row>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text>row,low,id,name&#xA;</xsl:text>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row/low"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="low">
    <xsl:text>row</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number count="row"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',low',position(),',',@id,',',@name,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
row,low,id,name
row1,low1,1d,bio
row1,low2,1d,bbn
row1,low3,1d,afs
row2,low4,1a,adn
row2,low5,1d,bio
row3,low6,1r,rio
row3,low7,1f,flo
```

Comment: thank you for you answer sorry but i forget to tell that i would like to show low1,low2,low3.. not only the number

Comment: @User04 - That should be easy; just add the text before `xsl:number` or `position()`. If it's not working for you, please update your question with the XSLT you're using and the desired output.